# Открытие href в том же окне

Tags: ajax, href, ссылки

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы ссылки вида `<a href="">` открывались в том же окне, а не в другом?

PS: как можно сделать минималистически, чтобы при нажатии на каждую ссылку вида `<a href="адрес"` в один и тот же контейнер аяксом загружался адру\ес ссылки, файл из адреса?Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Что вам нужно-то? =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте атрибут **target**.
[Описание](http://htmlbook.ru/html/a/target).

В Вашем случае используйте или **_self** или **_parent**.

```
<p><a href="new.html" target="_blank">Открыть в новом окне</a></p>
<p><a href="new.html" target="_self">Открыть в этом окне</a></p>
```

Comment: Ну, вот же оно! )) @Аsen, а вы понять не могли, чего хотел автор вопроса ;) Долой ajax! Даёшь target="_self"!

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, автор имел ввиду систему типа фрэймовой. То есть есть блок `100х100` и ссылки, при нажатии на которые в этот блок без перезагрузки страницы загружалась бы информация.

Я бы в таком случае посоветовал бы `Ajax` [табы](http://pcvector.net/scripts/tabs/278-ajax-vkladki.html). Вот [демо](http://pcvector.net/uploads/demo/scripts/tabs/ajax_tabs/index.html).